# Read in Bufferedimage pixel values then manipulate each one and write to file

Tags: java, rgb, bufferedimage, pixel, bitmapimage

I am currently trying to read in an image pixel by pixel and change each colored pixel to the rgb value of (100,100,100). For whatever reason when I check the values of each pixel one the image is saved it has all the colored pixels as (46,46,46) instead.

Here is the original image

[image]

After running my program this is the image it gives to me

[image]

Here is the code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Cmaps {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File originalImage = new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\0005.bmp");
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(originalImage);
            for(int i = 0; i < img.getHeight(); i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < img.getWidth(); j++){
                    //get the rgb color of the image and store it
                    Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(i, j));
                    int r = c.getRed();
                    int g = c.getGreen();
                    int b = c.getBlue();
                    //if the pixel is white then leave it alone
                    if((r == 255) && (g == 255) && (b == 255)){
                        img.setRGB(i, j, c.getRGB());
                        continue;
                    }
                    //set the colored pixel to 100,100,100
                    r = 100;// red component 0...255
                    g = 100;// green component 0...255
                    b = 100;// blue component 0...255
                    int col = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
                    img.setRGB(i, j, col);
                }
            }
            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\2\\1.png");
            try {
                ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have no clue why it doesn't set the pixels to the expected rgb value. I eventually want to be able to basically increment the rgb color as I move down rows and columns in the x and y so what the final image will look like is it will start off dark in the top left corner and then have a fade out effect as you get from that side to the bottom right corner.

Comment: Because your rgb (`int col = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;`) is set to a fixed value. Play with the `r`, `g` and/or `b` values and try to, for example, multiply (or something else) one (all or a few) of them by `i` or `j` and you'll see the difference. You are always setting the same value (`(100 << 16) | (100 << 8) | 100`) no matter what

Comment: The issue is they are not coming out as (100,100,100) even if i set them like that. Instead they will come out as 46,46,46 and I have no idea where it gets that number from

Comment: Before calling `img.setRGB(i, j, col);`, try setting the alpha with `col |= 0xff000000;`.  Also, be aware that the arguments to getRGB and setRGB are x and y coordinates, but you are passing the y coordinate (`i`) first and the x coordinate (`j`) second.  With a square image, it won't matter, but with other images you'll get an exception.

Comment: What type (`img.getType()`) is your `BufferedImage`? If it's a BMP, it may have an `IndexColorModel` (palette). With such a color model, you can't set the color of a pixel to an arbitrary value. If you try, the value will be changed to that of the closest matching entry in the palette.

Comment: Haraldk you are the man. It was a BMP file and when I used a png file it worked exactly as expected. Thank you a million times and for everyone who gave me feedback

Comment: Good stuff. Posted an answer below. The reason it worked using PNG, is most likely that the PNG was "true color" (24 or 32 bit). However, palette-based PNGs exists as well, so just changing the format to PNG isn't a completely fool-proof solution. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based on the comments:

If the `BufferedImage` has an `IndexColorModel` (palette based color model), using `setRGB` to set a pixel to an arbitrary RGB value will not work. Instead, the color will be looked up, and the pixel will get the color that is considered the closest match in the palette.

Formats like BMP, GIF and PNG may all use `IndexColorModel` when read using ImageIO.

To convert the image to "true color" (either `DirectColorModel` or `ComponentColorModel` in Java will do), you can use:

```
BufferedImage img; // your original palette image

int w = img.getWidth();
int h = img.getHeight();
BufferedImage trueColor = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics2D g = trueColor.createGraphics();
try {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
finally {
    g.dispose();
}

img = trueColor;
```

After this, `getRGB(x, y)` should return what you specify, using `setRGB(x, y, argb)`.